# Get ArrayList<String> from SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm saving my ArrayList in SQLite. Save codes:

```
public void HistoryADD(ArrayList<String> full, String owner){
    int size = full.size();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(FULL, full.get(i));
            cv.put(OWNER, owner);
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }
        System.out.println("added:" + full);
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Failed to add" + full);
    }
}
```

And IT's working. I want to get this ArrayLists from SQLite. List Code:

```
 public ArrayList<String> History_list(String owner) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> history_list = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE owner='"+owner+"'",
            new String[] {});

    cursor.close();
    return history_list;
}
```

But list code not working. What's wrong in this codes?
Thanks.

Comment: You never add the items from your cursor to your ArrayList so your History_list function always returns an empty array.

Comment: You should iterate your cursor and then add each item in the history_list array

Comment: How I Can add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do something like that:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(...);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //Here you have to add the item in your array list

    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> History_list(String owner) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
ArrayList<String> history_list = new ArrayList<>();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE owner"+"=?",new String[] {owner});
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int owner_value= cursor.getColumnIndex(owner);
        if (owner_value>0) history_list.add(cursor.getString(owner));
   }
cursor.close();
return history_list;
```

}